# What's the area of the triangle if one side and tan is given?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The triangle ABC is right-angled with a right angle at the corner C. Calculate the area of the triangle if c = |AB| = 10 and tan for B is 1/5.

I take it I have to use the area formula with sin, but I have no idea how... I have tried drawing a triangle, though without success.

Comment: What does "$C = |AB| = 10$" mean?

Comment: Oh, supposed to be a minor c. So the opposite side to the angle C = c and it's 10 units long.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $BC = x$, then $AC = 5x$. Now apply Pythagorean Theorem to get the equation and solve it for $x$. Now you know each side of the triangle. Can you proceed?

Comment: Note that $$\tan B = \frac{|AC|}{|BC|}$$ so you should have $|AC| = x$ and $|BC| = 5x$.